# How to order the files the way it is selecting in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qfiledialog

i have code which can select multiple files and print their names. But i found that they are not in order in which i am selecting them. say for example if i have file name as **file1,file2,file3**and if i first select **file2** then **file3** then **file1** while printing it is showing **file1,file2,file3** in this order. 
the code i have written is like this

```
    global desktop1
    global filesnames1
    file_name = QtGui.QFileDialog()
    file = file_name.getOpenFileNames(self, "Select the file to add", desktop1,
                                                      "source File (*.MOV;*.MP4)")

    filesnames1=list(file)
    for i in filesnames1:
       print i
```

please help how to achieve what i want.

Comment: I found the solution instead of declaring the variable as **list** we need to declare it as **set** coz list always sort the element where as set doesn't.

Comment: This is completely wrong. A set has no defined order. If you convert the list of files to a set, it will be pure coincidence if they appear in the order you wanted when you iterate over them. Try making a larger selection of files: it is almost certain they will appear in the "wrong" order when you iterate over them.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes u r right. Sorry for coming to d decision without checking it properly.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the [static functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#static-public-members) (like `getOpenFileNames`) will open a *native* file-dialog whenever possible. For native file-dialogs, Qt has no control over the order of the returned files, so there's nothing you can do to change it.

However, it seems that the *built-in* Qt file-dialog **does** return the files in the order they were selected. So if you don't need a native file-dialog, you can simply do this:

```
files = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
    self, "Select the file to add", desktop1, "source File (*.mov *.mp4)",
    options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    )
```

Comment: when trying with this code the .MOV or .MP4 files it is not showing. in fact it is not showing any files when trying with other file types

Comment: @RamakantaChandra. Well, I just copied your code, which I assumed was working. Anyway, I've edited my answer, which works fine for me on linux.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a method for that but you can write a function to get the selection and compare it to the previous one and connect that function to the activation of your QFileDialog :

```
global desktop1
global previous_selection
global filesnames1
QtGui.QFileDialog.currentChanged(get_selection)
file_name = QtGui.QFileDialog()


def get_selection(previous_selection):
    file = file_name.getOpenFileNames(self, "Select the file to add", desktop1,
                                                  "source File (*.MOV;*.MP4)")
    selected_files=list(file)
    if len(selected_files) > 1:
        current_file = selected_files-filenames1
        filenames1.append(current_file)
    else:
        filenames1=list()
        filenames1.append(selected_files[0])
```

I didn't try that code, but I think something like that would do the trick.

Comment: I didn't really expect it to work just like that (since I didn't try it), I just wanted to show you the idea of something which could work.
I'll try to come with something better once I get access to a python editor if no one answers first.